# Inverse connectivity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

Is it possible to have inverse connectivity in EF?

I have such example of code:

```
public class Team
{
    public Team ()
    {
        Players = new List<Player> ()
    }

    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public partial class Player
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public string Surname {get; set;}

    public string Position {get; set;}

    [Key, ForeignKey ("Team")]
    public int TeamRefID { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

The question is: is it possible, that I access the team of the Player from the Player class? If not - how to change the code to have such possibility?

Comment: you didn't show the Player class. however, to access Team from player, you should just add a navigation property in the player class.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Haven't I got navigation property in this part of code?

Comment: yes. you can access the team of any player with correct values (is probably not because PK is also FK).

Comment: Exactly, I suppose a `Team` will have multiple  `Player`s. So give the `Player` a `PlayerId` and rename `TeamRefID` to `TeamID`. No annotations are necessary then. Or do you explicitly want to create a one to one relation between `Team` and `Player`?